# Retry handler in Spring Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-retry

currently, I have Spring Integration Flow where reading payload from JMS queue, transforming to XML format, then send the XML payload to the core app. at the RecordSenderHandler, there is logic to make call rest API to my core app and store the response to Redis according to the response I received. If my core app is not accessible or something wrong with my backend, I flag as error HTTP 500. But I do want to retry the execution for certain times and limit maximum error I got. below is my code. any suggestions?

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlowWithContainer() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    Jms.container(this.jmsConnectionFactory, recordDestinationQueue)
                            .concurrentConsumers(xmlConcurrentConsumers)
                            .maxConcurrentConsumers(xmlMaxConcurrentConsumers))
                    .errorChannel("errorChannel"))
           .handle(payloadSender(), e->e.advice(circuitBreakerAdvice()))
            .get();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "handleChannel")
public PayloadSender payloadSender() {
    return new PayloadSender ();
}

  @Bean
public RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice circuitBreakerAdvice() {
    RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice requestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice = new RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice();
    requestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice.setThreshold(3);
    requestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice.setHalfOpenAfter(15000);
    return requestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain) and in particular the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`.

```
.handle(..., e -> e.advice(retryAdvice()))

...

@Bean
public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary, could you give me sample to use circuit breaker. I tried with this line   .handle(recordSenderHandler(), e->e.advice(circuitBreakerAdvice())) , but it doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is never enough information. Also adding code is comments is not good here; it doesn't render well. Edit the question with your current configuration instead, and explain exactly what you mean by "doesn't work" (and add a comment indicating you have done so). Enabling a DEBUG logging is also a good way to debug things.

Comment: please see my updated post for the code. I tried with RequestHandlerRetryAdvice  with retryPolicy and BackOffPolicy worked fine. I could see retry counter displayed at the log. But when I tried with RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice, it's like nothing happen. in this case, I stop the service of the core app to get error connection refused

Comment: thanks a lot. yeah, I get that. I'll raise the circuit breaker to separate question